# Spark: select with key in map

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to select with the key `geo.cc` in a `map` in a `DataFrame`:

```
 |-- params: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

but the value of the key, with its dot in the middle, seems to confuse Spark. If I write:

```
X.filter(X("params.geo.cc") === "us")
```

I get the error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from params#3[geo];
```

What can I do? (needless to say, I do not control the key, i.e. I cannot change that `geo.cc` string to e.g. `geo_cc`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `apply`:

```
val df = Seq((1L, Map("geo.cc" -> "US"))).toDF("id", "params")

df.select($"params"("geo.cc") === "US").show
// +-----------------------+
// |(params['geo.cc'] = US)|
// +-----------------------+
// |                   true|
// +-----------------------+
```

or `getItem`

```
df.select($"params".getItem("geo.cc") === "US").show
// +-----------------------+
// |(params['geo.cc'] = US)|
// +-----------------------+
// |                   true|
// +-----------------------+
```

on a specific column, not `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
X.filter(col("params")("key") === "geo.cc" && col("params")("value") === "us")
```