# How do I unpack a map in spark sql?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark data frame and one of the columns have values packed like this:

```
Map(a -> 123, name -> rover, type -> london)
```

How do I extract the value london and put it into a new column called type?

I tried

```
%sql

select map_field["type"] as type from myDF
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark: select with key in map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50705608/spark-select-with-key-in-map)

Answer (score 0):

You just select the column and add the key like the following:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
df.select(col("mapColumnName")("keyName"))
```